Stochastic Processes: Probability distribution transformation intuition
I have a question about the latter half of the following problem.

A die is "fixed" so that each time it is rolled the score cannot be
the same as the preceding score, all the scores having probability
$1/5$. If the first score is $6$, what is the probability $p$ that the
$n$th score is $6$? What is the probability that the $n$th score is 1?
Suppose now that a new die is produced which cannot score one greater
(modulo 6) than the preceding score, all other scores having equal
probability. By considering the relationship between the two dice find
the value of $p$ for the new die. (That is, find the probability that
the $n$th score is 6, given that the first score is $6$)

For the first part, I understand that we should just consider two states: 6 and $6^c$. I computed the relevant probabilities, and it was easy.
For the second part, I am having trouble relating the distribution of the first sequence and the distribution of the second sequence. The TA told me to consider $Y_n = X_n + n $ mod(6), where $X_n$ is the first sequence and $Y_n$ is the second sequence, but I don't quite understand this transformation. It intuitively makes sense, kind of (not really), because you don't want repeat values for $X_n$ so the $n$ allows you to "cycle" through, but this is all handwavy intuition. If anyone could formally explain this, with an example ideally, that would be ideal. So $Y_n = X_n + 2n$ work? Or any changing offset $n'$?

$\def\ed{\stackrel{\text{def}}{=}}$
If you define $\ Y_n\ed\,X_n+n\pmod{6}\ $ then you need to take the faces of the dice to represent equivalence classes mod $6$, with $\ 6\equiv0\ .$
The sequence $\ Y_n\ $ generated by the second die will be a Markov chain  with transition probabilities
$$
P\big(\,Y_{n+1}=j\,\big|\,Y_n=i\,\big)=\cases{0&if $\ j\equiv i+1\pmod{6}$\\\frac{1}{5}&otherwise.
}
$$
If you now define $\ Z_n\ed\big(Y_n-n\big)\pmod{6}\ ,$ then $\ Z_n\ $ will be a Markov chain with the same transition probabilities as the sequence $\ X_n\ $ generated by the first die, and $\ Y_n=i\ $ if and only if $\ Z_n\equiv (i-n)\pmod{6}\ .$ Therefore
\begin{align}
P\big(\,Y_n=6\,(\equiv0)\big)&=P\big(\,Z_n\equiv6-n\pmod{6}\,\big)\\
&=P\big(\,X_n\equiv6-n\pmod{6}\,\big)\\
&=\cases{P\big(X_n=6\big)&if $\ 6\,|\,n$\\
\frac{1-P\big(X_n=\,6)}{5}&otherwise.}
\end{align}
